# Use jqxGrid to render cell values that are objects?

Tags: javascript, jqxgrid

Is it possible in jqxGrid to render cell values that are objects?

E.g.  In this [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/__proto__/pen/EdKPEg?editors=1111)  each row has an attribute `details` which has an object value.   I'd like to say, make a custom renderer that displays the JSON stringified version of it, and a custom editor to modify it.

The challenge is that the row values appear as the string `"[Object object]"`:

```
var rows = [
  { color: "red", details: { a: 1, b: 2 } },
  { color: "green", details: { a: 2, b: 4 } },
  { color: "blue", details: { a: 3, b: 8 } },
  { color: "yellow", details: { a: 4, b: 16 } }
];
```

I tried creating a cell renderer, but the argument `value` is already squashed to the string `"[Object object]"` when the function is called.  Do I need to do something with the data adaptor to get the object value?

```
var cellsrenderer = function(row, column, value) {
  console.log(value);
  return "<div>" + JSON.stringify(value) + "</div>";
};

var columns = [
  {
    text: "Color",
    datafield: "color",
    width: 100
  },
  {
    text: "Details",
    datafield: "details",
    width: 200,
    cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer
  }
];
var source = {
  localdata: rows,
  datatype: "array"
};
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
  loadComplete: function(data) {},
  loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {}
});
$("#grid").jqxGrid({
  height: 600,
  width: 600,
  source: dataAdapter,
  pageable: true,
  pagesize: 20,
  autoheight: true,
  columns: columns
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var rows = [
  { color: "red", details: [{ a: 1, b: 2 }] },
  { color: "green", details: [{ a: 2, b: 4 }] },
  { color: "blue", details: [{ a: 3, b: 8 }] },
  { color: "yellow", details: [{ a: 4, b: 16 }] }
];
```

Comment: wild, why might arrays get passed as objects but not objects?

Comment: may be its limitation in jqxgrid